# Resources To Learn NewtonScript

Tags: newtonscript

Today I got my Apple Newton MessagePad 2000 and then I want to start developing for it. I already downloaded and installed the Newton Toolkit, but where I can learn NewtonScript?

Comment: The second google result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greetings, visitor from the past! Welcome to the 21st century. All restaurants are Taco Bell. Smoking is illegal. The Newton has been replaced by the iPhone. Happily, we have frozen a specimen of the documentation you seek, which you can read by activating [this magical portal](http://web.archive.org/web/20041010175535/www.cc.gatech.edu/~schoedl/projects/NewtonScript/)--it's something like Gopher. Fare well, and watch out for Skylab debris!

Answer (score 5):

The [United Network of Newton Archives (UNNA)](http://www.unna.org/) is a great collection for anything Newton related. For learning NewtonScript, I'd recommend checking the [Development/Documentation](http://www.unna.org/view.php?/development/documentation) section. As Avi commented, "Programming for the Newton" is a great starting point, and it can be found in that section as a downloadable HTML version, but I would definitely recommend reading the official "Newton Programmer's Guide" as well. Further, the NTK comes with example code which is very instructive.

Another way of digging in is to use ViewFrame (also on UNNA) which lets you inspect any existing NewtonScript application directly on the Newton. That can be very helpful if you are wondering how an application does certain things.

Answer (score 2):

Wow.... a blast from the past.

Julie McKeehan and Neil Rhodes wrote several excellent Newton programming books. If you can locate any copies of *Programming for the Newton*, do so. Make sure to get the second edition, which covered the 2.0 version of NewtonOS.

And hang out at www.newtontalk.net.

-Avi, bigtime Newton nerd from long ago

Answer (score 2):

Morgant Aldridge has recently launched a site which gathers a vast assortment of NewtonScript resources under one roof. The [newtonscript.org](http://newtonscript.org/) site contains information about the language itself, development tools for various platforms, libraries with NewtonScript interfaces, and other programming reference materials.

You can also contribute to the site through [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/NewtonScript/newtonscript.github.com).